# PhiloGL -> propagate transformation between models

Tags: webgl, webgl-extensions

I have a scene showing one object in multiple models. Each model displays the object at a variable state.
There's a slider to switch between multiple models.
My problem is that when the user rotates the view and changes to another model, the rotation will be lost and the new model is displayed at the initial camera / viewport position.
Hence - how can I force the current camera transformation on the new model?

```
$("#slider").change(function(){
  var i = $('#slider')[0].value;
  myscene.models = new Array();
  myscene.add(mymodels[i]);
  myscene.defineBuffers(mymodels[i]);
  myscene.render();
});
```

Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 1):

Isnt it called PhiloGL ? Please share code for review - how you are sharing, storing and restoring states. In WebGL, you need to store/restore transformations explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is update the transformations of the new model, try this:

```js
var copyTransformations = function (target, src) {
    target.position = src.position;
    target.scale = src.scale;
    target.rotation = src.rotation;
    target.update(); // if you call the update for the target model in another place, but before the render will work to
};

copyTransformations(newModel, oldModel);
```

Comment: not working for me yet. rotation = [0,0,0] for all models, even when I rotate them